# Closing Tabs in Svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to make a tab system in svelte. I have all of the basics done, except for the fact that I can just not figure out how to make it so that a tab closes. When I try removing the top tab from my tab array it just updates the other undeleted tab with the top tab's content. [Demo](https://svelte.dev/repl/0f34b340182c44b09806ddaac806272a?version=3.53.1)
and [GitHub](https://github.com/notAperson535/arc-browser-svelte/)

I don't know why the demo messes up the tabs when you click on one, that is not a problem on my local code.

(I'm new to svelte and StackOverflow, so please don't hate on me if this has an obvious answer or duplicate)

Script

```
  $: tabsandiframes = [{id: 1, src: "https://www.google.com/?igu=1"}, {id: 2, src: "https://bing.com"}];
    $: console.log(tabsandiframes)

  let nextid = 4;
  let newnextid = "";
  var tabOrder = new Array();

  function openTabAndIframe(id) {
    if (tabOrder.indexOf(id) > -1) {
      tabOrder.splice(tabOrder.indexOf(id), 1);
    }
    tabOrder[tabOrder.length] = id;

    if (
      typeof document.querySelector("iframe.active") !== "undefined" &&
      document.querySelector("iframe.active") !== null
    ) {
      document.querySelector("iframe.active").style.display = "none";
      document.querySelector("iframe.active").classList.remove("active");
    }

    var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
    iframes.forEach((elmnt) => {
      elmnt.style.display = "none";
    });
    var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    iframe.classList.add("active");
    var tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
    tabs.forEach((elmnt) => (elmnt.className = "tab"));
    var pinnedtabs = document.querySelectorAll(".pinnedtab");
    pinnedtabs.forEach((elmnt) => (elmnt.className = "pinnedtab"));
    if (iframe.src !== "") {
      iframe.style.display = "block";
    }
    var tab = document.getElementById("tab" + id);
    tab.className += " active";
  }
  function closeTabAndIframe(id) {
    // var tab = document.getElementById("tab" + id);
    // var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    // tab.outerHTML = "";
    // iframe.outerHTML = "";

    console.log(tabsandiframes.indexOf(id));
    tabsandiframes.splice(tabsandiframes.indexOf(id), 1);

    tabsandiframes = tabsandiframes;

    tabOrder.splice(tabOrder.indexOf(id), 1);
    openTabAndIframe(tabOrder.slice(-1)[0]);

  }
```

Svelte HTML

```
  {#each tabsandiframes as tabandiframe}
    <div
      class="tab"
      id={"tab" + tabandiframe.id}
      on:click={() => openTabAndIframe(tabandiframe.id)}
      on:keypress={void 0}
    >
      <img alt="Tab Icon" src="https://github.com/notAperson535/arc-browser-svelte/blob/master/public/img/tabfavicon.png?raw=true" class="tabfavicon" />
      <p>Tab</p>
      <img
        on:click={() => closeTabAndIframe(tabandiframe.id)}
        on:keydown={void 0}
        alt="Close tab"
        src="https://github.com/notAperson535/arc-browser-svelte/blob/master/public/img/closetab.png?raw=true"
        class="invert tabclose"
        listener="true"
      />
    </div>
  {/each}

{#each tabsandiframes as tabandiframe}
  <iframe id={tabandiframe.id} src={tabandiframe.src} title="iframe" />
{/each}

<svelte:window
  on:load={() => newTabAndIframe()}
  on:load={() => openTabAndIframe(4)}
/>
```

I was trying to make the old tab's content disappear, but instead the tab below it would always inherit the content of the tab removed above it. Basically, if I removed the top tab, it would end up just removing the bottom tab.

Comment: Too much code. Create a minimal example that isolates the issue you are trying to fix. Also, don't query the DOM, use `bind:this` or actions (`use:...`).

Comment: Is that better (in terms of the code minimizing)? And, in terms of the DOM stuff, I'll look into that

Comment: Not significantly. Ideally it should fit onto about a page and be directly pasteable into the REPL. It is still hard to tell if the issue is the use of array methods instead of reassignment, the DOM manipulation or the lack of [keys in the `each`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-each) (usually it's that).

Comment: I have tried using keys, and it didn't change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it like this, with id's mentioned by [@H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/h-b)

```
  {#each tabsandiframes as tabandiframe, i (tabandiframe)}
```